# Calling an AlertDialog in another class from a button onClick in another Activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-alertdialog, buttonclick

I want to call my AlertDialog "DeleteConfirm" in my Alerts.class from my AccountManager.class through a button onClick event. How do I go about this without affecting the AlertDialog's ability to delete an entry from my database.

EDIT: I have tried calling `Alerts.DeleteConfirm(con, acc);` before and ended up with a "Cannot resolve method `con` and `acc`" respectively. If someone could show me how to properly pass `con` and `acc` into the onClickListener that should fix it.

If there are any pieces of code that are missing for reference please feel free to ask.

AlertDialog "DeleteConfirm" snippet:

```
public class Alerts extends Activity {



public static void ShowAccAddedAlert(Context con)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(con);
    builder.setTitle("Add new Account");
    builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
    DialogListener listener=new DialogListener();
    builder.setMessage("Account Added successfully");
    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", listener);

    AlertDialog diag=builder.create();
    diag.show();
}

public static AlertDialog DeleteConfirm(final Context con, final Account Acc) {


    AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(con);
    b.setTitle("Account Details");
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(con);
    View v = li.inflate(R.layout.delete, null);
    b.setView(v);

    b.setPositiveButton("Yes", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(con);
            db.DeleteAcc(Acc);
        }
    });

    b.setNegativeButton("No", null);

    return b.create();

    }
}
```

AccountManager button onClick snippet:

```
public class AccountDetails extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.accdetails);

 Button delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO CALL MY DeleteConfirm AlertDialog
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Pass Context and Account class object to call `DeleteConfirm` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside `delete.OnClickListener()` call `Alert.DeleteConfirm(con, acc);` and replace `(con, acc)` by `(your_class'_context, object_of_Account_class)`

Comment: Ran into problems when I did this before, I put the details in an EDIT above.

Answer (score 1):

Better way, create one java class (Utility.java), write your DeleteConfirm(Context context) method there and call it from both activities.

Create Util.java plain java class, paste below code there,

```
public static void alertDialogShow(Context context, String message)
        {
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alertDialog.setMessage(message);
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
              } 
            }); 
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

Now from your Activities call

```
Utils.alertDialogShow(MyActivity1.this,"Alert Message 01");

Utils.alertDialogShow(MyActivity2.this,"Alert Message 02");
```

Comment: How exactly does that help? I'm sorry, I'm still learning so I can't really see how moving it to another class and referencing it into Alerts.class and AccountManager.class can fix the problem.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes more sense now. Thanks for that, I might use that later on for something else but for now someone got it working for me. Thanks for the alternative though :)